# Running database tasks while server is running

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rails-activerecord

I am designing a Rails 4 application where there is a need of creation of tables (or even adding/removing columns on an existing table) on a MySQL database while the server is running. In the future I might even need relationships between a table created through rake to the one created while the server is running (therefore I will also need means to update the database schema and create/update models)

I am thinking that I can make my way around ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) but to access the database created by raw SQL I would have to write another SQL to select the table.

Is there a way I can achieve this by convention?

**The need for database tasks while server is running is no longer needed though I would like to know how to operate more conveniently just for the sake of future problems and research purposes**

**DATABASE STRUCTURE HAS BEEN CHANGED TO A MORE CONVENIENT ONE TO BE LESS COMPLICATED ON DB-END AND MORE DYNAMIC ON FRONT-END**

<s>The architecture I am planning will be:</s>

1. The user, through the application will create a new Assignment The
   Assignment will have its own table created with the title and the id
   of the Assignment, i.e: homework_assignment_id
2. The Assignment table will have columns according to the dates of
   users input i.e: Homework Assignment will take place between the
   dates 15.08.2015, 16.08.2015, 17.08.2015 so the column names could
   be 15082015 and so on
3. The Homework Assignment will have sub-Projects i.e: Project One,
   Project Two, Project Three Each Project will have different number
   of contributors on different days i.e: Project One on 15.08.2015
   will have 2 contributors, 16.08.2015 will 5 and 17.08.2015 1 and
   Project Two with 2, 4, 6
4. I will create the same table twice and populate it with the contributor IDs in dates
   columns and will have the first table keep track of maximum number
   of contributors a Project will have

Example tables:

Table **plan_homework_assignment_31**

```
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
|    Title    | 15082015 | 16082015 | 17082015 |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Project One |        2 |       5  |       1  |
| Project Two |        2 |       4  |       6  |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Table **homework_assignment_31**

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
|    Title    |    15082015     |    16082015     | 17082015 |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
| Project One | [1, 15]         | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | [id]     |
| Project Two | [4, 22]         | [id*4]          | [id*6]   |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

OR Table **homework_assignment_31**

```
+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+
|      Title      | 15082015 | 16082015 | 17082015 |
+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Project One(x4) | 1        | 1        | 1        |
| Project One     | 15       | 2        | null     |
| Project One     | null     | 3        | null     |
| Project One     | null     | 4        | null     |
| Project One     | null     | 15       | null     |
| Project Two(x6) | 4        | 4        | 4        |
| Project Two     | 8        | 16       | 16       |
| Project Two     | null     | 9        | 9        |
| Project Two     | null     | 21       | 21       |
| Project Two     | null     | null     | 1        |
| Project Two     | null     | null     | 51       |
+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Is there a better way of creating this kind of structure by the database itself, not through the application? If not how can I achieve this through the Rails application?

Note: Coding in Rails and SQL is not the topic, the means used are.

Note: Database will be normalized!

Thank you for your input.

Comment: I think you have a data normalization issue and if so you need to `alter table` on the fly a lot which is a problem. Would you care for a fresh perspective on data normalization that would solved all of the above (as I quickly read it)

Comment: @Drew I checked the normalization technique and am watching youtube videos explaining NFs. Thank you for your suggestion, I will update my question to contain only Rails related topic :)